# Converting String to NSDate in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an API sending date in string with universal time but when I try to convert to NSDate format it tends to return nil. I have looked in lot of places but couldn't find a way to resolve this. Below is my code that I have written. Please help me to find where am I going wrong. The string I'm trying to convert is "Sun Feb 14 23:35:40 UTC 2016". The problem causing it to return nil is with the time zone I believe.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy"
dateFormatter.dateFromString("Sun Feb 14 23:35:40 UTC 2016")
```

Comment: @matt I was trying this in playground so I could see the result without capturing it.

Comment: Your string has a "UTC" in it, but your format doesn't match that (need `zzz` at that spot). Also 23 hours is `kk` not `hh`

Comment: @matt I have handled UTC in the timezone.

Comment: Obviously you haven't. `timezone` has nothing to do with the string format. It is a property of what the date _is_, not how it is _formatted_.

Comment: okay! thanks for clarifying my misunderstanding.

Comment: @NiranjanRavichandran If your date time goes from 0 to 23 hours you need to use HH not kk as matt suggested. kk is for 1 to 24 hours which it is probably not what you want. The correct date format would be `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy"
let d = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Sun Feb 14 23:35:40 UTC 2016")
```